# Laravel route, GET paramters in routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

**What we want to do**

Get clean url like this

`domain.com/student/query/your+search+query`

`domain.com/student/subject/subject-name/chapter/chapter-name`

subject-name, chapter-name is parameter

`domain.com/student/subject/subject-name`

subject-name is a paramter

**problem**

how to create those urls for form get method

**what we have done**

using javascript right now

Comment: Have you tried - `domain.com/student/subject/{subject_name}/chapter/{chapter_name}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use sth like this:

```
Route::get('student/query/{query}', SearchController@search');
```

in your search controller you will then have the variable $query available like so

```
public function search($query) {
    //do your search magic here
    //and return a correct response (JSON, view,...)
}
```

for multiple parameters the story is similar

in routes

```
Route::get('student/subject/{subjectName}/chapter/{chapterName}', SubjectChapterController@show');
```

and then in your SubjectChapterController

```
public function show($subjectName, $chapterName) {
    //fetch the data, return the view,...
}
```

what you should be a bit careful is that you place the routes in the order of most specific to more general. If i remember correctly, as soon as a match to a pattern is found the other routes are no longer checked (not 100% sure about this).